# Angular - Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I am trying to get data from a json file. but getting error Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.
Please review my code

Serivce.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Car } from './car';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AddressService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCarsSmall() {
    return this.http.get('./cars-small.json')
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => <Car[]> res.data)
                .then(data => { return data; });
}
}
```

.json file

```
  {
    "data": [
        {"brand": "Volkswagen", "year": 2012, "color": "White", "vin": "dsaf"},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345"},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr"},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh"},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "White", "vin": "hrtwy34"},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj"},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr"},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "White", "vin": "greg34"},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5"},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please add your template code.

Comment: check like this. res["data"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because when you navigate to your page, you are trying to render `data` variable before your service response.

And my prediction is that you are not using `*ngIf` clause on you template side,

Try this approach,

```
<ul *ngIf="data">
   <li *ngFor="let item of data">
     {{item.brand}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

For your service side, you don't need second `.then` block,

```
  getCarsSmall() {
    return <Car[]>this.http.get('./cars-small.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => { return data; });
  }
```

Comment: for a background, the question originates from the PrimeNG documentation for tables:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table